# MSSQL wildcard for excluding one or more characters

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, wildcard

I have stored a json array in a single column in a SQL table (MSSQL Server). Now I wanna filter some rows using LIKE "pattern" and wildcards. The stored object is something like this:

```
[{"id":"W678","value":"282779"},
 {"id":"O891","value":"25896"},
 {"id":"E859","value":"12711"},
 {"id":"M914","value":"31513"}]
```

and for example, I wanna filter rows which their's JSON array has an element with "id"="W678" and value that contains "27"

In the case of using regular expression the following regex worked for me:

```
/.+{"id":"W678","value":"[^{}]*27[^{}]*"}.+/
```

But I don't know how to translate the above regex into a SQL wildcard expression.
I have tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
LIKE '%{"id":"W678","value":"[^{}]%' + @Value + '[^{}]*%"}%'
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Sql Server

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later: [Microsoft: JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov Sql Server 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach is to parse the JSON array and return its content as a table using [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and explicit schema in the `WITH` clause. Then, with a set-based approach, you can filter the content and find the matching rows.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (JsonData varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO Data (JsonData) 
VALUES ('[
   {"id":"W678","value":"282779"},
   {"id":"O891","value":"25896"},
   {"id":"E859","value":"12711"},
   {"id":"M914","value":"31513"}
 ]')
```

Statement:

```
 SELECT d.*
 FROM Data d
 CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (d.JsonData) WITH (
       id varchar(4) '$.id',
       value varchar(6) '$.value'
    )
    WHERE [id] = 'W678' AND [value] LIKE  '%27%'
 ) a
```

Note, that explicit schema definition depends on the structure of the JSON array.